# Android Studio Tests are successful but do not stop junit

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, testing, junit

I am new to Android and building an app in Android Studio. I have written some tests using JUnit and Mockito.

The tests run successfully and in the run console the text `Process finished with exit code 0` is shown.

However, the thread seems to remain active, the stop button is enabled and nothing happens even if I click on it. If I try to start multiple test configurations, they all remain active although the processes finish successfully.

I hope the question is clear enough... I have searched a lot for the answer and mananged to find nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That can be fixed by following these steps:

1. Open 'Run' tab in Android Studio
2. Tap 'X' next to test which has just passed

[image: Android Studio Guide]

Comment: This is still an issue and I'm happy I came across this answer. The stop/stop all button doesn't work and I was almost going crazy.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so after a little more research and some more checking I have concluded that the problem stands in a visual bug of Android Studio. Apparently the tests do indeed stop, the thread running them too. The problem is purely visual.